# How to compress JSON

Tags: java, php, json

I have a webservice sending a huge JSON text to an Android app. There's about 20000 ID numbers. Unfortunately but perhaps not surprisingly it's timing out.

What options do I have? The easiest one that comes to mind is somehow compressing this data. Is there any way I can do this (PHP webservice, Java Android app) effectively?

Failing that, is there some technique to send JSON in parts? If so, how does that work? At what point is JSON considered too big to send in one part? Thank you

Comment: Can you paginate your data?  If so, I'd recommend **paginating your data.**

Comment: Gzipping response might help to an extent, but the long term solution is to paginate as suggested by @Makoto

Comment: How is paginating data typically done in PHP/Java for JSON?

Comment: How about reduce the list...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GZIP in php and send as stream to client and then decode data with java in android

you can use this for gzip in php: [GZIP](http://www.geekality.net/2011/10/31/php-simple-compression-of-json-data/)

and Gzip in Android : [GZIP](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-file-from-gzip-file/)

Answer (score 0):

You could compress data with ob_gzhandler(). Put this call in your script before any output:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

After that, output will be compressed with gzip.

This is not a good solution, indeed. You should split JSON and send it as sequential smaller pieces. Otherwise, what will you do when even compressed data is too big?